# Nginx Add static path /v1 to all of the frontend urls

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I want to add a static path like /v1 to all of front urls hosted on a server.

Currently i am using redirect but when i click any other link in the frontend "/v1" is missing and calling the actual url provided in code

Comment: Can you share your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
  sub_filter "'/" "'/algo/";
  sub_filter '"/' '"/algo/';
  sub_filter_once off;
  sub_filter_types *;

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

By adding sub filter the problem is solved